# EasyAdmin 3 Only List data belonging to logged in user

Tags: easyadmin

I just recently migrated from easyadmin 2 to easyadmin 3 and in my lists i can now see all the data from the entitiy (e.g. Company).
In easyadmin 2 it automatically (at least that´s what i guess) limited the output belonging to the logged-in user.

I have read that i can set custom functions for each Controller like

```
 public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
    {
        if (!in_array("ROLE_ADMIN",$this->getUser()->getRoles())) {
            $qb = $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
            $qb->andWhere('entity.creator = :user');
            $qb->setParameter('user', $this->getUser());
            return $qb;
        }
    }
```

but that can´t be the solution i guess since somehow it worked in easyadmin 2 as well without having to write custom indexQueryBuilder functions.

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have roles ADMIN, MANAGER, COURIER, so my code:

```
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\SearchDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Orm\EntityRepository;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Collection\FieldCollection;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Collection\FilterCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

class LuggageManagerCrudController extends AbstractCrudController 
{
   public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
    {
        $qb = $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);

        if (in_array('ROLE_MANAGER', $this->getUser()->getRoles())) {
            $qb->andWhere('entity.manager = :user');
        } else {
            $qb->andWhere('entity.courier = :user');
        }

        $qb->setParameter('user', $this->getUser()->getEmail());

        return $qb;
    }
}
```

And I have another AdminCrudController for ADMIN's roles